# Json to Java with SpringBoot and Rest Template

Tags: json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have implemented a module to consume a rest webservice(Json) and persist in oracle database. I only worked on Spring IOC but could quickly developed it using Spring Boot Rest Template and Spring Data JPA. Number of classes are very less.

for json to java object conversion, i used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  and copied all generated java objects my project.  Now i want to include the logic/maven target to convert json to java objects.

Can anyone suggest, is there any simplified way to this with spring boot rest?

Thanks.

Comment: Spring boot uses **jackson** for Json to java and vice versa. You can use it or you can use **Gson**, too.

Comment: What do you mean by "using spring boot rest"? Is your spring boot endpoint being called and is the client sending JSON?

Comment: Yes, i called a spring boot endpoint, and it returns Json data.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same question and after a lot of digging into the dirt I came across an open source library, [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/). It helps in java beans mapping and generates code for you at the time your application boots up. It worked fine for me. Give it a go.

Comment: Using spring boot and data jpa, it simplified many things like i didn't even wrote any code to use Datasource. I configured datasource in my JBoss standalone.bat and provided 'spring.datasource.jndi-name'  in application.properties.  so my query is, is there any such simple way to convert json to java also?

Comment: just going through MapSturct, is it compatible with Eclipse also?

Comment: @user7220859 Yes. It is compatible with Eclipse and MapStruct converts json to java and the code is generated in the fly, you wont have to write it.

Comment: can you provide me some useful links for same? if you already have any.